# Long process under Swing GUI : unexpected delay

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

To explain my question here is an MCVE where clicking clicking a `JButton` on `JDialog` A opens `JDialog` B:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class  DiagA extends JDialog  {

    private DiagB diag;

    public  DiagA() {

        super();
        setTitle("main diag");
        setSize(200, 150);
        setLocation(400,400);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Show DiagB");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                showDiag();
            }
        });
        add(btn, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //make main frame visible
        setVisible(true);
    }

    void showDiag() {

        if(diag == null) {

            diag = new DiagB();

            //this prints out as expected
            System.out.println("set visible done");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

            //only after the delay diag shows in full
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new  DiagA();
    }
}

class DiagB extends JDialog  {

    public  DiagB() {

        super();
        setTitle("2nd diag");
        setSize(150, 100);
        setLocation(600,420);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code I added a 3 sec delay after creating `DiagB`.
Clicking the button `DiagB`shows like this:

[image]

Only after the 3 sec delay ends, `DiagB`shows in full:

[image]

My questions are: 

a. Why doesn't `DiagB`show completely after it is constructed ? (It shows in full only when `showDiag()` returns). 

b. The reason for my question is that `DiagB` needs to be updated, by long processes in `DiagA`. 

What is the right way to update ? Does it require using a `SwingWorker` for every updating process ?

Comment: If it's for display rather than user interaction, it shouldn't be a `JDialog` which is for, well, dialog with the user. And there should *never* be a sleep (or any other long operation) in an event handler.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I understand what you are saying about long operations in an event handler.( `JDialog` or `JFrame` will not make much difference in this case. A `JDialog` might be needed for modality for example).

Comment: Modality implies user interaction is immediately needed. Otherwise, it's not used correctly.

Comment: Great question! Yes, a `SwingWorker` is the way to go for this one..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for the feedback. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a. `showDiag` runs on the GUI thread. The GUI will be completely dead while you make the GUI thread sleep.

b. Yes, use a `SwingWorker` for long-running tasks and use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to submit GUI-updating tasks back to the GUI thread. Alternatively, implement `SwingWorker#done()` which is a convenience method that runs on the GUI thread after the `SwingWorker` task completes.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you are saying "schedule action for later". Using a `SwingWorker` for every updating process is a beat cumbersome. I would rather implement it in the updated (`DiagB`) object. Any advice ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Note the OP used the sleep to ***simulate*** a long running task, so their suggestion of a **`SwingWorker`** down near the bottom of the post seems the best strategy for this.

Comment: @AndrewThompson True, I updated to recommend `SwingWorker`+`invokeLater`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Marko Topolnik answer and Andrew Thompson comment,  I warped the long process with a `SwingWorker`.

This works fine:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class DiagA extends JDialog  {

    private FrameB frame;
    private JButton btn;

    public  DiagA() {

        super();
        setTitle("main frame");
        setSize(200, 150);
        setLocation(400,400);

        btn = new JButton("Show Frame B");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                show2ndFrame();
            }
        });
        add(btn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    void show2ndFrame() {

        if(frame == null) {

            frame = new FrameB();
            btn.setText("Exit");

        }else {

            System.exit(0);
        }

        doWork();
    }

    private void doWork() {

        SwingWorker<Void, Void> sw = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

                try {

                    for(int i = 1 ; i<=100 ; i++) {
                        //represents a long process
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        frame.update(i);
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
                return null;
            }
        };
        sw.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new  DiagA();
    }
}

class FrameB extends JFrame  {

   JLabel label;

    public  FrameB() {

        super();
        setTitle("2nd frame");
        setSize(150, 100);
        setLocation(600,420);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        label = new JLabel("0");
        add(label);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    void update(int progress) {

        label.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
    }
}
```